# Como dañe este archivo?

Tags: android-studio, kotlin

Soy nuevo programando en kotlin android estudio y programacion en general, dañe este archivo, no me reconoce los valores que coloco, y antes me salian unas ayudas al escribir y ahora no sale nada.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Saludos, a mí me pasó varias veces. Prueba de cerrar el Android Studio y vuélvelo a abrir (asegúrate de cerrarlo del todo). Suerte, ojalá eso sirva.

Comment: Si situas el puntero del mouse sobre ese problema, ¿Qué es lo que sale? ¿Se solucionó cerrando y abriendo AndroidStudio?

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Answer (score 0):

> Paso 1
> **clean project**
>
> Paso 2
> **rebuild project**
>
> Paso 3
> **make project**

**Si esto no funciona, presiona 2 veces la tecla SHIFT** y busca la opción "Invalidate caches / restart"